# Which is the best way to implement timeout for HTTP request in Android?

Tags: java, android, apache, http

That my sample!

```
private void onGet( String command, int requestType ){
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://" + getHost() + ":" + getPort() + getServerCgiPath() + command);
    Client.sendRequest(getRequest, requestType, getCallBack() );
}
```

... Right there i have created my HttpClient

```
    public class Client {    
public static void sendRequest(final HttpUriRequest     request, 
                                     int                RequestType,
                                     ResponseListener   callback    ) {
    (new AsynchronousSender(new DefaultHttpClient(), request, RequestType, 
                            new Handler(), new CallbackWrapper(callback))).start();
}
```

}

...

```
public class AsynchronousSender extends Thread { 
private DefaultHttpClient httpClient; 
private HttpUriRequest    request;
private Handler           handler;
private CallbackWrapper   wrapper;
private int               requestType;
protected AsynchronousSender( DefaultHttpClient httpClient, HttpUriRequest request,
        int requestType, Handler handler, CallbackWrapper wrapper ) {
    setRequest      (request);
    setHandler      (handler);
    setWrapper      (wrapper);
    setClient       (httpClient);
    setRequestType  (requestType);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        final HttpResponse response;
        final HttpParams httpParams = getClient().getParams();  
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout  ( httpParams, 5000 );
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout          ( httpParams, 5000 );
        Log.d("Ehome", "before execute reauest");
        response = getClient().execute( getRequest() );
        Log.d("Ehome", "post execute reauest");
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        switch( status ){
            case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
                getWrapper().setResponse(response);
                getWrapper().setRequestType(getRequestType());
                getHandler().post(getWrapper());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private HttpClient getClient() {
    return httpClient;
}
```

...

Answer (score 1):

[HttpConnectionParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html) is the class to use:

Example code (as uncompleted as yours :-))

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
```

So you have to do it something like this (without checking your code deeply):

```
    public class Client {    

        public static void sendRequest(final HttpUriRequest request, 
                                       int RequestType,
                                       ResponseListener callback) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
        (new AsynchronousSender(httpClient, request, RequestType, 
                            new Handler(), new CallbackWrapper(callback))).start();
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, i've improved my sample.

Comment: I do not understand your code! The relevant part is where you create your httpClient. On this client you can change the HttpParams. That should work. If you show this code (maybe it's your `getClient`) I maybe can help you.

Comment: I created client and after that was run the thread where i have executed request!

Comment: I don't see the difference between my code and yours (except deeply level) it should be working in the both case, but i checked it anyway, and it didn't worked. =( May be you know any new way to do this?

Comment: I do not know any other way. I do it that way and it works. Did you check that 5000 milliseconds are enough to avoid the timeout?

Comment: This code should work. Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say it does not work ?